# Where is Sigi from?

Tags: norse, volsunga

In the Saga of the Völsungs, we learn that the patriarch Sigi is exiled from his homeland and eventually becomes a king in the land of the Huns (or France, according to the Prose Edda). However, the name of his homeland in not mentioned.

Do we know where Sigi is originally from?

Comment: Jesse Byock, in the title of Chapter 1 of his translation of *The Saga of the Volsungs,* claims Odin guides him from "the Otherworld."

Comment: You should post this as an answer @BrianDonovan